# What does the table {block_node_type} use for in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

The table description is that "Sets up display criteria for blocks based on content types."

so how can drupal relative with content types?

Answer (score 1):

In each block's visibility settings, you can choose whether the block should appear if the current node belongs to a specific content type.

Adminiter > Structure > Block > [click "configure" in the block]

This is new in Drupal 7.